# Adding two buttons to UIStackView horizontally one covers the other

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, constraints, uistackview

So I'm trying to add two buttons of equal width to my view next to each other. I have used a stack view as I thought this would work better.
The second button named "Sort" is only one visible at the correct width but covers over my "Add" button leaving and empty space next to it.
I have run it without the "Sort" button and I just get the "Add" button showing across the whole stack view as I would expect so bit confused but this.
Code is below not sure what's going on with it. If think its better to not use stackView need just a little bit of advice on best way to work the constraints. Thanks everyone.
And just to say I'm working only in programmatic with this.

```
import UIKit

class PlacesVC: UIViewController {


let topTitle = UILabel()
let logoImage = UIImage(named: "DIYCoffeeLogoDark")
let logoImageView = UIImageView()
let addButton = UIButton()
let sortButton = UIButton()
let buttonStack = UIStackView()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.view.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.9324248433, green: 0.9268818498, blue: 0.9366856217, alpha: 1)
    logoImageView.image = logoImage
    self.navigationItem.titleView = logoImageView
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden = false
    view.addSubview(topTitle)
    view.addSubview(buttonStack)
    setUpTopTital()
    setUpButtonStack()

}

func setUpTopTital() {
    topTitle.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    topTitle.font = UIFont(name: "Futura", size: 25)
    topTitle.text = "Your Saved Places"
    topTitle.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 100).isActive = true
    topTitle.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
    topTitle.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor, constant: -20).isActive = true
    topTitle.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30).isActive = true
}

func setUpButtonStack() {
    buttonStack.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    buttonStack.addArrangedSubview(addButton)
    buttonStack.addArrangedSubview(sortButton)
    buttonStack.distribution = .fillProportionally
    buttonStack.alignment = .center
    buttonStack.axis = .horizontal
    buttonStack.spacing = 20
    buttonStack.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topTitle.bottomAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
    buttonStack.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    buttonStack.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: view.frame.width - 40).isActive = true
    buttonStack.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30).isActive = true
    setUpAddButton()
    setUpSortButton()
}

func setUpAddButton() {
    addButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    addButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Futura", size: 20)
    addButton.setTitle("ADD", for: .normal)
    addButton.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.3176470697, green: 0.07450980693, blue: 0.02745098062, alpha: 1)
    addButton.layer.cornerRadius = 5
    addButton.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
}

func setUpSortButton() {
    addButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    addButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Futura", size: 20)
    addButton.setTitle("SORT", for: .normal)
    addButton.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.3176470697, green: 0.07450980693, blue: 0.02745098062, alpha: 1)
    addButton.layer.cornerRadius = 5
    addButton.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
}
```

Comment: You `setUpSortButton` isn't setting up your `sortButton`. It's setting up your `addButton `

Comment: Oh yea thats crazy. Been staring at that code for going on an hour. Completely code blind on that. thanks mate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In both functions, setUpAddButton() and setUpSortButton() you are using same button that is addButton.

Change addButton to sortButton inside setUpSortButton(), then you are able to see both buttons in your stackview.

```
func setUpSortButton() {
    sortButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    sortButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "Futura", size: 20)
    sortButton.setTitle("SORT", for: .normal)
    sortButton.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.3176470697, green: 0.07450980693, blue: 0.02745098062, alpha: 1)
    sortButton.layer.cornerRadius = 5
    sortButton.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
}
```

Comment: Yea I see it now. Cant believe that. Been staring at that code for going on an hour. Completely code blind on that. thanks mate